# Fill the common region by color

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
%ymajorgrids=true,
%xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-7.0,
xmax=7.0,
ymin=-7.0,
ymax=7.0,
xtick={-6,-5,-4,-3,...,6},
ytick={-6,-5,-4,-3,...,6},]
\clip(-5.,-5.) rectangle (6.,6.);
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={-90:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=1pt,color=sexdts,domain=-8:8] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/2});
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={0:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=1pt,color=rvwvcq,domain=-8:8] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/2});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (4,4) circle (3.0pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.8,3.5) node[left,above] {$A(4 , 4)$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (3.0pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.9,-0.5) node [right,below,rotate=00]{$O(0 , 0)$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Question: How can i fill the common region (that means between (0 , 0) and (4 , 4)) with color?

One more Question: I want to draw arrows on both the negative axes as well as four tails of these two curve. Is it possible?

Comment: With fill between, page 430 of the pgfplots manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to first question with `fillbetween` library:

1. Load `fillbetween` library
2. Add `name path` to each involved line
3. Add `fillbetween` plot

This is what was done here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
>=stealth,
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={stealth-stealth},
%ymajorgrids=true,
%xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-7.0,
xmax=7.0,
ymin=-7.0,
ymax=7.0,
xtick={-6,-5,-4,-3,...,6},
ytick={-6,-5,-4,-3,...,6},]
\clip(-5.,-5.) rectangle (6.,6.);
\addplot[samples=50,rotate around={-90:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=1pt,color=sexdts,domain=-8:8, name path=A] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/2});
\addplot[samples=50,rotate around={0:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=1pt,color=rvwvcq,domain=-8:8, name path=B] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/2});
\addplot[orange] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={(0,0) rectangle (4,4)}];
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (4,4) circle (3.0pt);
\draw[color=black] (4.8,3.5) node[left,above] {$A(4 , 4)$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (3.0pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.9,-0.5) node [right,below,rotate=00]{$O(0 , 0)$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result, looks like:

[image]

Comment: Happy with this solution. But what about arrows? Which i want to draw at negative x-axis and y-axis even at tails of parabolas

Comment: Please help me. --> this type of arrow

Comment: See the desirable output image which i added in my question.

Comment: Try using `\addplot[<->]`.

Comment: @Thevesh Would you please explain in details?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `\draw[<->]`. Basically adds the arrow option to a line.

Comment: @snehal I don't know how to add arrows to plotted lines, but for axis, just add `axis line style={stealth-stealth},` `somewhere after `axis=middle` option.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: @snehal    It does for me. Look at updated code and result.

Comment: Yup. Now it is. Thanks still waiting for required arrows on graph. Does anyone can ?

Comment: @snehal Ignasi has answered your problem. It is preferable that you accept its solution to your problem, which is now solved. Then ask a new question for the placement of the arrows.